# Without .PHONY target is getting built when a file named as target already exists in current directory

Tags: makefile

While going through MakeFiles I found that when the file named as target is present even then without using .PHONY, target is getting built. 
But when I am doing the same with another target i.e. clean, then target is not getting built and saying "clean is up-to-date" which is OK.
I just want to know why the other target is getting built when the file exists in the current directory.

makefile:

```
CC:= gcc
CCFLAGS:=-Wall -Wextra
hello: hellomake.o hellofunc.o
        $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) hellomake.c hellofunc.c -o file
hellomake.o : hellomake.c
        $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) -c hellomake.c
hellofunc.o : hellofunc.c
        $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) -c hellofunc.c
clean:
        rm -rf *.o
        rm -rf file
```

---

My current directory has file named same as the target, as "hello".
It should give result as "hello is up-to-date" but it is not doing it and giving the output as :
make hello

```
gcc  -Wall -Wextra  hellomake.c hellofunc.c -o file
```

Please tell why is this building the target when the TARGET IS NOT .PHONY AND THE FILE NAMED AS TARGET ALREADY EXISTS IN CURRENT DIRECTORY.

Comment: If the `hellomake.c` or `hellofunc.c` is latest than `hello` it will rebuild. Run the `make hello` twice you can see on second time it will give hello is uptodate

Comment: `I just want to know why the other target is getting built when the file exists in the current directory` you should rather check if target is rebuild even if the dependency are not modified.

Comment: After creating files which I have used in the makefile, I am creating "hello" file in my directory. But still makefile does not give any error, even when it is not having .PHONY.  Normally when the file named same as the target is present in the current directory, it should not run the commands of the target, without using .PHONY but here in my case it is doing this. :)

Answer (score 5):

Because `make` looks at the last-modified times to decide what to build. From the [`make` manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Preparing):

> The `make` program uses the makefile database and the last-modification times of the files to decide which of the files need to be updated.

The command `make` examines the time relationships between the target and its prerequisites. If the prerequisites have been modified after the target it means that the target is out of date and the rebuild is triggered even if the file is present. So most likely your dependencies have been modified after the target.

In order to avoid this behavior, you can:

- Use [`touch`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/touch) to change the target timestamp.
- Use `make -t hello` or `make --touch hello` before invoking `make hello`. From the [docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Instead-of-Execution.html):

> ```
> ‘-t’
> ‘--touch’
> Marks targets as up to date without actually changing them. In other words,
> make pretends to update the targets but does not really change their
> contents; instead only their modified times are updated.
> ```

Comment: The best way to avoid this behavior is to simply use the name of the file that the recipe creates as the target, which is how make is intended to work.  So if your recipe builds a file named `file`, as the above recipe does (`gcc ... -o file`), then the target name should be `file`, not `hello`.  Then it will all work as expected.